# if I click the project,the "active" don't move to project

Tags: angularjs

**JS**

```
mainApp.controller("leftmenuController", function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.check = function(event) {
        $('li').removeClass('active');
        $(event.target).addClass('active');
    };
});
```

**Html**

```
<li class="active" ng-click="check($event)"><a href="#/firstpage">Link</a>
<li ng-click="check($event)"><a href="#/project"></a></li>
```

if I click the project,the "active" don't move to project. 
what's wrong with my code.

[image]

Comment: is your check method getting called in the first place ?

Comment: use `$(event.target.parentNode).addClass('active');`

Comment: @KaushalNiraula from the screen it seems the active class is not removed only.

Answer (score 5):

> what's wrong with my code

It's not using angular as it's meant to be used. You should **never** do DOM manipulation in a controller. The controller should only change the model, and the view should use angular expressions and directives to generate HTML based on this model.

So you should have something like

```
<li ng-class="{active: activeLink === 'first'}" ng-click="checkLink('first')" ...>
```

and

```
<li ng-class="{active: activeLink === 'project'}" ng-click="checkLink('project')" ...>
```

And the controller should just do

```
$scope.checkLink = function(link) {
    $scope.activeLink = link;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
    $scope.activeMenu = 'firstpage';
    $scope.check = function(menu) {
        $scope.activeMenu = menu;
    };
```

HTML

```
<li ng-class="{'active':activeMenu=='firstpage'}" ng-click="check('firstpage')"><a href="#/firstpage">Link</a>
<li ng-class="{'active':activeMenu=='project'}" ng-click="check('project')"><a href="#/project"></a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it without jquery

```
<li ng-class="setActive('#/firstpage')"><a href="#/firstpage">Link</a>
```

And in the template

```
$scope.setActive= function (path) {
  return ($location.path().substr(0, path.length) === path) ? 'active' : '';
}
```